# How to repair video files?

Tags: video, data-recovery

I have a corrupted micro SD card. With huge trying I could to recover it's data using **recuva** tool, but now my files are corrupted also. They are video file with some famous extensions such as 3gp, mp4, flv, wmv, avi. My video file players are *VLC* and *Media player classic*. The *media player classic* says, "can not render the file" and *VLC* doesn't show anything.

Is there a way to repair these video files?

Answer (score 1):

The chances are that when you were recovering them tiny bits of the code was eater not there or left behind. This will make the video corrupt and it will be almost impossible to repair the code, even with hours and hours of work the most you could get would be able to get would be a few seconds in total, and these will not be in one piece. Most of them you wouldn't even be able to recover at all. Sorry but I think you may of lost them unless some one else has any suggestions.

You could try this [link](http://blog4mark.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/how-to-repair-corrupted-pen-drive.html)

Comment: OK, I'll wait for a solution.

Comment: Some one has posted an answer you may want to give that a look.

Comment: Yes I read that and tried to get back my data using that tool but it couldn't to return any thing!!

Comment: Is there any hardware device to repairing such cards?

Comment: You could try this [link](http://blog4mark.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/how-to-repair-corrupted-pen-drive.html)

Comment: Tried. The result was nothing!

Comment: I don't have any more suggestions the best thing you could do is offer a bounty because this will attract a lot of people to the question.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get your mean correctly.

Comment: I mean you can offer reputation as bounty on questions this attracts attention to the question. [See here](http://superuser.com/help/bounty)

Comment: OW sorry I don't have 15 scores to give an answer a reputation. I don't know what else I can do.

Comment: I don't think there is much more you can do.

Comment: And should throw it away?

Comment: It hurts but it sometimes it is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you the applicaton called **GetDataBack for NTFS / FAT**, you can download it from the following link: http://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm

You might find it a bit costly but it's worth the price, it has saved my life on several occasions!

Bare in mind though (as the gentleman before me already mentioned) if the USB stick / hard drive is corrupted some of the files GetBackData will recover will be faulty (eg.: part of the mp3 file will be static, missing frames in movie files) but it can still recover most of the things from your USB / hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood was, you got back your videos, but it is corrupted. Recuva is nice software and I hope you have got all the videos. Since the videos are corrupted, that cannot be fixed with recovery software if i am not wrong. You need to use a video repair software.
You can check this free software: http://www.risingresearch.com/en/dvr/
If possible create a copy of the video file and then repair, because I am not sure whether this software directly repairs the original file.
If this doesn't work, I would recommend you to go for some paid software. Check this if it is of any help:http://www.hi5software.com/repair/unable-to-play-mov-file.html